# Typescript error when declaring array: Type 'Report[]' is missing the following properties from type …

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have this dummy data and I want type:

```
export default interface Report {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  lastName: string;
}

export const dummyReports: Report[] = [
  { id: 23, name: 'Carlo', lastName: 'Magno' },
  { id: 11, name: 'Albert', lastName: 'Camus' },
  { id: 51, name: 'Oliver', lastName: 'Khan' }
];

export const dummyReportsArr: Report[] = [
  dummyReports, // THIS IS THE LINE THROWING THE ERROR
  { ...dummyReports, id: 9000 }
];
```

`Type 'Report[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Report': id, name, lastName ts(2739)`

What am I missing?

Comment: `dummyReports` is of type `Report[]` (`Array`) and you're trying to put it in place where single `Report` is expected

Answer (score 0):

You have set `dummyReportsArr` to be of type `Report[]`. But, you're assigning this 2D array to it

```
dummyReportsArr = [
  [ {}, {}, {} ], // dummyReports
  { 0: {}, 1: {}, 2: {}, id: 9000 } // an object with numeric indices
]
```

The first item in the array is `dummyReports` array. The second one is an object. Spreading an array inside `{}` creates an object with indices of the array as the keys of the object. Neither of these are of type `Report`